# MySQL - Relational Databases and Tagging

Tags: mysql, sql

*I have been scratching my head on this one for a while, so I figured I'd ask stack overflow (Note: I am an SQL novice trying to learn more SQL, so please be respectful and explanatory):*

I have one sql table that looks like this called "posts":

```
id | user
--------------------------------
0  | tim
1  | tim
2  | bob
```

And another called "tags" that stores the tags on the posts (in the "posts" table) in text:

```
id | postID | tag
--------------------------------
0  | 0      | php
1  | 2      | php
2  | 0      | mysql
3  | 1      | mysql
4  | 1      | sql
5  | 3      | perl
```

(To clarify, the concept where: id=0 is tagged php,mysql; id=1 is tagged sql,mysql; id=2 is tagged php; id=3 is tagged perl.)

**How could I write a WHERE statement to get posts tagged x, but not y (x and y will be defined by php)?**

For example, how could I get all posts tagged mysql but not php?

### EDIT

Could you also explain how to add multiple tags to search for (for example get all tagged mysql and recursion but not php)

Comment: +1 for really good task, not easy to do in sql.

Comment: I prefer to use left join for that, not exist predicate. See my answer.

Comment: ...recursion is something that's not easy to do in SQL. If you look at your own answer, this is basically one `LEFT JOIN` with a `pk IS NULL` predicate.

Comment: @todda, yes, I know, I wrote it :) ... what are you trying to say?

Comment: Your comment that this is not easy to do in SQL is wrong.

Comment: @todda, well, depends how you define easy ;-) not obvious, at least :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naively, simply and portably:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tags.postid = posts.id AND tags.tag = 'x')
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tags.postid = posts.id AND tags.tag = 'y')
```

Now depending upon the execution plan, you can do other things to optimize this.

Comment: I may be completely off base here, but couldn't I do: `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tags.postid = posts.id AND tags.tag = 'x') AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tags.postid = posts.id AND tags.tag = 'x2') AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tags.postid = posts.id AND tags.tag = 'y')` for multiple tags? Am I missing something....

Comment: @Tomas - yes, but you either have to add the ANDs and AND NOTs in some kind of dynamic fashion - either in client code or in SQL using a string and then MySQL's PREPARE feature.  Alternatively you could set them up with a fixed but large number of parameters and handle NULLs as iff they were NOOPs.  There's typically not a portable "array" handling feature in ANSI SQL.  It would certainly be nice.  Each dialect has either features or idiomatic workarounds.

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
from
    (select distinct postID
    from tags
    where tag = "mysql") as t1
left join
    (select distinct postID
     from tags
     where tag = "php") as t2
using (postID)
where t2.postID is NULL
```

example 2: get all tagged mysql and recursion but not php:

```
select *
from
    ((select distinct postID
    from tags
    where tag = "mysql") as t1
join
    (select distinct postID
    from tags
    where tag = "recursion") as t3
using (postID))
left join
    (select distinct postID
     from tags
     where tag = "php") as t2
using (postID)
where t2.postID is NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, Could you also explain how to add multiple tags to search for (for example get all tagged mysql and recursion but not php)

Comment: @Tomas, OK, see the updated post. You just add another subquery to the join.

Comment: @Tomas Telensky: What if you wanted to check 3 tags? 4? 5? Our queries aren't evolutive, they don't really answer the problem.

Comment: @Vincent Are you telling me that what I am asking is essentially impossible, or there is a way (that isn't overly convoluted/hackish) that just takes a different approach? If it is simply a matter of adding subqueries can't I write a loop in php to add joins to the query before executing it? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Tomas: I would know how to do this with PostgreSQL for instance, but MySQL doesn't support arrays or recursive queries to make such a query easy. I don't see how to do it without doing a lot of joins or subqueries. Sure, you could construct this query with PHP, but I doubt it would be very efficient.

Comment: @vincent, you have to put many values to the query condition anyway, so whether you put values or subqueries is almost not important on the php level... on the sql level the performance would be interesting, however - depends on the optimizer... however, as you noted, we are not aware of better solution in mysql now.

Comment: @Tomas There isn't anything standard and portable which would let you expand this inline in plain SQL.  There is a trick where you can do a `WHERE tag IN (SELECT tag from includelist) GROUP BY postid HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM includelist)` - but making that include list has to be done with dynamic SQL at some level.

Comment: @Cade, what you mean with dynamic SQL? You can use temporary table and insert the values there, but you probably mean something else...

Comment: @Tomas Yes, you can make a temporary table, but to populate it from a single delimited string parameter, you'll probably have to use dynamic sql or a cursor or something.  If the table is populated outside of the process or the process might be running in several places at once it becomes more problematic.  In SQL Server, there are table-valued parameters which make this example extremely easy.

Comment: @Cade, that would be great. Which SQL server you mean? (However also note that temporary tables in mysql are connection specific, so there wouldn't be a race condition on it.)

Comment: @Tomas SQL Server 2008 and up - they can be used within a procedure pretty much the same as a regular table or table variable.  Makes small-medium batch inserts, master/detail inserts, multi-select option searches etc much simpler in a single proc instead of multiple procs with a transaction managed throught a client library BeginTransaction etc.

Comment: @Vincent and Tomas, Wouldn't my comment on Cades' answer demonstrate a query string that could be dynamically constructed in php that would work?

Comment: @Tomas, yes, this also should work, it's the same principle as here. However as I said I prefer the join solution as I know joins are optimized well and I'm sure the query will go fast, whereas the solution with `EXISTS` looks to be quadratic at the first sight and seems to be harder to optimize

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion with EXISTS :

```
SELECT DISTINCT postID
FROM tags t1
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT NULL
             FROM tag t2
             WHERE t2.id = t1.id
               AND t2.tag = 'x')
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                   FROM tag t2
                  WHERE t2.id = t1.id
                    AND t2.tag = 'y')
```

Comment: coming to the rescue again (didn't you answer one of my questions yesterday)! Could you also explain how to add multiple tags to search for (for example get all tagged mysql and recursion but not php)

Comment: MySQL doesn't know recursion, so as far as I know, you would have to do one join/sub query for every tag you want to look at. You could probably work around a solution around GROUP_CONCAT, but that really feels hackish. I'll write the query in my answer.

Comment: Thank you, the goal of this exercise is for me to learn (and get a handle on how I am going to build a tagging system :D), +1 you have definitely helped me a lot.

Comment: @Tomas : I take back what I said, actually GROUP_CONCAT would be *okay* if you wanted to select, for instance, the posts having exactly the "php" and "mysql" tags, not containing them. I don't know how to do what you're looking for with MySQL.

Comment: What do you mean? It would work for posts that ONLY had those two tags? Or something else?

Comment: With `GROUP_CONCAT`, you could merge all the tags into one string (for example, `mysql,php,recursion`). So it would be easy to check if one post has all of the tags with one query, but not so easy if you want to check if it contains mysql and recursion, but not PHP.